# Getting view to use correct region automatically

Tags: view, tags, atk4

As mentioned in an earlier question of mine, I'm new to ATK4 and I'm currently learning, so there might come a few more question. Now to my issue.

I've created a region "`Sidebar`" in my template `shared.html` and adding the view to it like this:

```
class Frontend extends ApiFrontend {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        /* 
            Other stuff here
        */

        $this->addLayout('Sidebar');
    }

    function layout_Sidebar() {
        $this->add('View_Menu', null, 'Sidebar');
    }
}
```

Then I'm creating the view like this:

```
class View_Menu extends AbstractView {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->add('HtmlElement')
            ->setElement('a')
            ->setAttr('href', 'testurl')
            ->set('Link');
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Spot is not found in owner's template

Additional information:

    spot: Content
```

Supplying the add function with `$this->template->top_tag` as third argument solves this problem:

```
$this->add('HtmlElement', null, $this->template->top_tag)
    ->setElement('a')
    ->setAttr('href', 'testurl')
    ->set('Link');
```

...but do I really have to add that to every add() call in the view? It doesn't seem right and I'm quite sure it's not!

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's not a View I should use, maybe I should create it as an extension of HtmlElement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating AbstractView, you need to specify a default template. By default your AbstractView will use the region of  from your shared.html. In other words AbstractObject assumes the template of the region it replaces.

when you create defaultTemplate() or pass 4th argument to the add() you can specify a different file to be used for template of your sidebar menu.

In either way - the template should contain a  where output of any sub-elements will be displayed.

You may inherit from "View" class which already relies on the custom template containing just a . Your idea of using HtmlElement is just like this, because HtmlElement extends View.